# Concatenating dataframes from a for-loop when empty dataframes are included

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation

I have a list of about 2000 companies and the EODHistoricalData API that returns earnings projections for each of those companies by period. Each of the company's data is its own dataframe. The dataframe needs to be transposed to make the dataframes consistent across companies. I'm hoping to loop through a list of tickers through the projections API and append all the data together. It works w/ a handful of names but when I try to execute the full list I'm given an error when concatenating.

Below are the steps I use and the results:

The dataframe comes out properly when I call a handful of companies:

```
test_ticker_trend = []


for ticker in test_tickers_df['ticker']:
    try:
        web_add =  "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/{ticker}?api_token=APIKEY&filter=Earnings::Trend"
        web_add = web_add.format(ticker = ticker)
        web_df = pd.read_json(web_add)
        transpose_df = web_df.transpose()
        transpose_df['ticker'] = ticker
        test_ticker_trend.append(transpose_df)
    except:
        test_ticker_trend.append('0')

test_ticker_trend_df = pd.concat(test_ticker_trend, ignore_index=True) 
test_ticker_trend_df
```

However, when I try to run a loop on a large set of companies (w/ several empty dataframes), I get an error when trying to concatenate (the API itself runs runs fine):

*TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"*

Below is the result of the API call loop before it's converted:

[image]

Comment: You should take a look at the pd.concat documentation, it has examples of how to properly use it.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: Thanks. I did look through that but didn't find much help -- I'm a beginner. I tried a bunch of different approaches both in the for loop and using concat once the dataframes were appended. I'm sure there's just a step I'm missing as someone new to this -- I think it has to do w/ there being empty dataframes.

Comment: Instead of converting every json to data frame I would pack JSONs converted to dictionaries into list. And when loop is over would convert the list to data frame.

Comment: I'm out of API calls for the day ha but I will test this tomorrow. Is it just a function of changing this 'web_df = pd.read_json(web_add)' to a list rather than dataframe?